# Injected fields becoming Null after Self Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where i need to call methods inside my Bean using Bean instance and not directly to execute some actions on every method, So after searching for some suggestions I found that self injecting a Bean into itself and calling methods can work but every time I refer some other injected field, i get a Null pointer exception. I am calling ServiceA.methodA() from some other Bean for testing.

Code:

```
@Component
public Class ServiceA {

@Autowired
ServiceB serviceB;

@Autowired
ServiceA dummyService;

public void methodA(){
dummyService.methodB();
}
public void methodB(){
serviceB.getData();  //Service B is null here;
 }

}
```

I get null pointer exception when trying to access serviceB bean inside self injected Bean, I tried several solutions like getting dummyService from applicationContext , using @PostConstruct but none seems to work. Can anyone help me understand whats incorrect in this approach?

Comment: I doubt that this is the exact code you are using and that there is a missing `final` or non public method that is being called.

Comment: i am calling ServiceA's method A from some other place. Added in description

Comment: again please add the code as is. I suspect you are using a `final` method or a non public method whch won't be properly proxied, leading to calls onthe proxy instead of passing it trhough to the underlying instance. It doesn't matter if ou call methodb from the outside, the import thing is the state of the method on the self-reference.

Comment: Agree with M. Deinum. I've tested your exact exposed scenario and it works.

Comment: got it, yes the method was private. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @M.Deinum any resource which will help in better understanding of how these proxies work?

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any way to do this on a private method? There were numerous stack overflow posts that showed you could create the self-reference in the class and self-inject  and call other methods on that reference and it would work , even on private methods, but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting a Null pointer exception every-time on the variable that is the "self" reference in my class.

Comment: @ennth it seems:
1) if you want self reference (e.g. for new tx), you have to use self.xxx instead of this.xxx
2) if you want to keep the injected objects, the function xxx should not be private, default or final